# separate number by piping Angular

Tags: angular

How can I separate this number `1234567890' to`1,234,567,890` with using pipe Angular ?
I try it by this code but show me: 1,234,567,890,000

```
{{ item.price | number:'3.3' }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
{{ item.price | number: '3.' }}
```

This will remove the digits after decimal.

Comment: It's work thanks, but when I remove `: '3.'` and then works

Answer (score 2):

In order to get rid of the extra 0's and to produce 1,234,567,890
Use the following pipe:

```
{{ item.price | number: '3.'}}
```

output:

```
1 234 567 890
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct format is to set `3.0-0` to remove the digits after decimal.

```
{{31544543.512 | number :'3.0-0'}} // => 31,544,544
```

Check the sample section at [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)